# Can I Used wamp server as a db for my web api C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, wampserver

I am creating my first webapi on visual studio. I used wamp server as a database and my problem is, I dont know how to connect wamp on my webapi. Is it posible to use wamp instead of microsoft sql server? plss help me guys

Comment: YES it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this c# code

```
 string connstring ="Server=localhost;Database=testDB;Uid=UserName;Pwd=yourPassword;";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
    connection.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Connected");
connection.close();
```